# KDE: move window to top left shortcut key (not tiling/no resize)

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

I've just come from cinnamon and I used to use  <kbd>`</kbd> key to move the current window to the top left of the screen, I can't find the option in settings apart from tiling which shrinks the window to a quarter of the screen as well which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kubuntu 16.04 with [kubuntu backports ppa](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72006-Latest-round-of-backports-PPA-updates-include-Plasma-5-10-2-for-Zesty-17-04?p=401636&viewfull=1#post401636) enabled to have Plasma 5.8.8, it is possible in two steps.

For example, in `System Settings` > `Global Keyboard Shortcuts` > `KWin` I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (Pack Window Up) to move the window to the top and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (Pack Window to the Left) to move the same window to the left. No resizing occurs.

You can, of course, use some other keyboard shortcuts, but I'm not sure you can use just a single key as you can in Cinnamon.

Comment: Thanks that's a huge help, I didn't even try that as I assumed packing a window would shrink it. Using a single key does work btw. I have upvoted you but my rep is too low for it to count right now. I'm not marking as solved quite yet though.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 22.04 (Plasma 5.24.6) you can set shortcuts for this in `System Settings > Shortcuts > KWin` and set the `Move Window Down`, `Move Window Up`, `Move Window Left`, `Move Window Right`, `Move Window to the Centre`.

These commands do not resize the window.

Moving a window to the top left without resizing it would involve move up and left...